# Can I use CoreFoundation and Foundation methods in C++ in a iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, foundation, core-foundation

I'm building an iOS app which half of it is in C++ and half in Swift.

I wonder if I can import and call methods from `CoreFoundation` and `Foundation` in the C++ part of the app without having to call to the Objective-C and Swift part of the app.

Thanks

Comment: "Can I use CoreFoundation and Foundation methods in C++ in a iOS app" - did you *try*? That would answer the question pretty fast and conclusively 

Comment: There is a lot of C-API which can be used directly from C++. For example: [CFMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfmutablestring?language=objc) - and this can be cast for free to `NSString*`. Not everything is available in C-API form. Only choice is to scan documentation what is available form C-API and what not. Also bridging between C++ and Objective C is quite simple and pleasant.

Comment: If you rename your file to have a `.mm` extension, Xcode will see the source file as *Objective-C++*, some batard language will all features of C++ **and** all features of Objective-C. Quite handy.